# Can I upgrade the Radeon Pro graphics card in my iMac early-2008?

Tags: imac, upgrade, gpu

I have a 20″ early-2008 iMac with Radeon Pro (256 MB) and I wish to upgrade it. Are there any suitable (and more powerful) replacements for it (the video card)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes you can (although it may involve a firmware upgrade):

http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+20-Inch+EMC+2133+and+2210+Video+Card+Replacement/1014

(Taken from: http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/90234/Can+I+change+my+graphics+card)

Comment: can you suggest a suitable replacement?

Comment: Nvidia 8800 GS - Apple Part # 661-4664 is the best you can get for that model I believe (however, it's NOT cheap..).  This page should allow you to find the different options available for your model which will give you the different Apple Part Numbers: http://www.ifixmaccomputers.com/apple-parts-video-cards Once you have those, you should be able to use google to find performance vs cost ratings and find the best card that fits your budget.

Comment: I did a little digging and found this site: http://www.macpalace.com/661-4664-video-card-nvidia-geforce-8800-gs-24-inch-2.8-3.06ghz-imac-early-2008-a1225-mb325ll.html It looks like it's 295.00 for the 8800 GS; they also have the 7300GT for 199.00 and the ATI Radeon 2600 Pro for 229.00.

Comment: The Macpalace page referenced in the above comment notes that it's compatible with the **24"** 2008 iMac. Mactracker concurs that that card was an option on the 24" iMac, but not the 20". Is there any reason to believe that this card will work in the OP's 20" machine?